# VB.NET Check for keydown on dragdrop

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, keypress, keydown

I've tried searching quite a bit for this answer but haven't been able to find a good solution.

I have a datagridview on my form where users can drag and drop files onto the grid and certain columns are filled in.  This works fine.

I want to be able to check if a user has a certain key pressed at the time the file is dropped.  If so, I want to use that to add specific data to one of the columns in the datagrid.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I have used keydown outside of dragdrop before but it seems that I'm missing something.  The code I have is below. No matter what I do, I never get "T is pressed" but I always get "T is not pressed".

```
Private Sub frmReader_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    Dim files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
    If Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.T) Then
        MsgBox("T is pressed.")
        ' Put certain info into the datagridview
    Else
        MsgBox("T is not pressed.")
        ' Put other data into the datagridview
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use function [KeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Key)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown?view=netcore-3.1). It´s referenced in `PresentationCore.dll`. You also need to reference `WindowsBase.dll`

Comment: A lot of information is available, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=vb%20.net%20how%20to%20drag%20and%20drop&ac=5

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Do you just need the `ModifierKey` or any Key?

Comment: I have used other keydown events never with a combination of the dragdrop function. I put my code above. I don't need any modifier key.

Answer (score 0):

God, embarassing...  I changed "Keys.T" to "Key.T" and it's working fine.  Sorry for the bother.